# Sort object array list based on total value

Tags: java, oop, sorting, arraylist

I calculate each student's total mark. Then I add those object into a array-list. What I want to do is based on this total mark (not a property of Student object), sort my array list and display student details with total mark. I have a no idea how to do this. Can someone suggest me a good optimized my to get this work done??

```
public static void TotalModuleMarkAboveAvg(){
        double totalModuleMarkAvg = OverallClassAverage(false); //getting the avg of the total marks
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        double studentTotalModuleMark = 0.0;
        student = new Student();
        System.out.println("List of students whose total module marks fall below the class average ");
        for(int i=0; i<MAX_STUDENT; i++){
            Student student = vector.get(i);
            studentTotalModuleMark = student.getCoursework1()*20/100;
            studentTotalModuleMark += student.getCoursework2()*20/100;
            studentTotalModuleMark += student.getFinalExam()*60/100;
            if(studentTotalModuleMark > totalModuleMarkAvg){
                students.add(student);
            }
     // here I want to sort my array list based on the studentTotalModuleMark and display student registration number and total module mark
        }

    }
```

student class

```
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable{
    private int registrationNumber;
    private int coursework1;
    private int coursework2;
    private int finalExam;

    public int getRegistrationNumber() {
        return registrationNumber;
    }
    public void setRegistrationNumber(int registrationNumber) {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }
    public int getCoursework1() {
        return coursework1;
    }
    public void setCoursework1(int coursework1) {
        this.coursework1 = coursework1;
    }
    public int getCoursework2() {
        return coursework2;
    }
    public void setCoursework2(int coursework2) {
        this.coursework2 = coursework2;
    }
    public int getFinalExam() {
        return finalExam;
    }
    public void setFinalExam(int finalExam) {
        this.finalExam = finalExam;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Sorting will be a real headache without having the total as a field. You would need a corresponding array to hold the total. And while sorting the Arraylist MANUALLY, sort the corresponding array indcies.  Why not have the total as a field?

Comment: Also, I have a feeling you want your ArrayList placed outside of the method. Makes a whole lot more sense.

Comment: And why do you have two student variables inside you method. Not good practice.

Comment: Yah true, since the total can be derived run time, thought I don't need it as a field. And I can change the weightage of the each module runtime. But it seems I have a no option other than add total as a field.

Comment: You don't need it, but you SERIOUSLY want it. If you have it as a field, you can do the magical `Collections.sort()` trick. Just need to have your method implement COmparable. I'll put up an answer in a but to show you

Comment: Ah thanks I'll make it to a student. Any idea how to get this done. I mean what's ur suggestion?? adding a new field as a Total or ??

Comment: means a lot of u can show me how to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>, Serializable {
    private int registrationNumber;
    private int coursework1;
    private int coursework2;
    private int finalExam;
    private int totalScore;

    public Student(int registrationNumber, int coursework1, 
                             int coursework2, int finalExam) {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
        this.coursework1 = coursework1;
        this.coursework2 = coursework2;
        this.finalExam = finalExam;
        totalScore = coursework1 + coursework2 + finalExam;
    }

    ...
    // all you getters and setters
    ...



    public int compareTo(Student s){
        if (this.totalScore > s.totalScore)
            return 1;
        else if (this.totalScore == s.totalScore)
            return 0;
        else 
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Now Everything is set up for you to use the `Collections.sort()` method

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

Student student1 = new Student(1, 90, 70, 100);
Student student1 = new Student(2, 85, 43, 90);
Student student1 = new Student(3, 67, 70, 80);

students.add(student1);
students.add(student2);
students.add(student3);

Collections.sort(students);
// Magic!
```

**Edit: Using anonymous Comparator**

```
public class ComparatorPractice{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

        Student student1 = new Student(1, 90, 70, 100);
        Student student1 = new Student(2, 85, 43, 90);
        Student student1 = new Student(3, 67, 70, 80);

        students.add(student1);
        students.add(student2);
        students.add(student3);

       Collections.sort(students, new Comparator(){
           @Override
           public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){
               if (o1 instanceof Student && o2 instanceof Student){
                   if (o1.coursework1 > o2.coursework1)
                       return 1;
                   else if (o1.coursework1 == o2.coursework1)
                       return 0;
                   else
                        return -1;
               }
           }
       });

       System.out.println("Highest coursework1 mark is " 
                           + students.get(students.size()- 1).coursework1);

       Collections.sort(students, new Comparator(){
           @Override
           public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){
               if (o1 instanceof Student && o2 instanceof Student){
                   if (o1.coursework2 > o2.coursework2)
                       return 1;
                   else if (o1.coursework2 == o2.coursework2)
                       return 0;
                   else
                        return -1;
               }
           }
       });

       System.out.println("Highest coursework2 mark is " 
                           + students.get(students.size()- 1).coursework2);
    }
}
```

Just do the same for each component you want to sort by. If you do it this way, without using `Comparable`, you don't need the `compareTo()` or the `implements Comparable` in your `Student` class.

Comment: Means a lot.. Highly appreciate

Comment: I'm not sure how you wanted totalScore calculated, so just do the calculation yourself.

Comment: yah sure, this is more than enough!!

Comment: additional question.. can I use multiple "compareTo" to sort my ArrayList multiple time?? I'm little confused.

Comment: You mean let it be sorted in different ways? You can't have more than one compareTo(). But if you want them to be able to be sorted differently, you can use an anonymous comparator for each time you try and sort.  Other than that, I may not be understanding your question.

Comment: All the compareTo() method does is tell Java how to your `Students` are compared (what makes one greater than the other).

Comment: You can use the method more than once though, like if you sort it once, then add a bunch more students to the list, then sort again.

Comment: yah i think u got it. I want to sort my ArrayList 4 times
based on coursework1, coursework2, finalExam, totalScore. how to use anonymous comparator for each time

Comment: Yeah you can use it as many times as you want. You can keep adding more to the list, and keep sorting so the list stays in order after whatever you add.

Comment: yah how do I add anonymous comparator for each time

Comment: So you mean there are times when you want to sort it NOT by increasing total score order?

Comment: yah without doing any changes, I want to sort it. My prime ambition is to get the maximum mark of each component(coursework1,coursework2,finalExam,totalScore) with student details.

Comment: I don't really understand, So after sorting the list, you want to sort each students scores individually to get that students high score?

Comment: Ohh I see what your saying. You need to sort it by different components. Wait a few minutes. Ill update my answer

Comment: ok let me put it on this way. All my objects are stored in a Vector. So I want to find the highest score for each component and overall module separately and display student details and their marks.so can u please suggest me a good way to get this done??

Comment: You can use a comparator sort for each component. But remmber, once you sort it, then sort it with a different comparator, the previous sort can no longer be obtained. So after a sort, you may want to do all your actions, then complete another sort for a different component. See my edit. It sorts my classwork1. You cant do the same for all the other components. Just switch the `classwork` to something else.